# Calculating division between two columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm experiencing some trouble when calculating a division between two columns in SQL.
So far I have written this:

```
SELECT s.ccode, (1-(ygrade/xnumber))*100 AS flow
FROM
( SELECT COUNT(s.ccode) AS xnumber
FROM Studied s
) x
JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(grade) as ygrade
FROM Studied s
WHERE grade <> 'U'
) y on x.ccode = y.ccode
```

Which is obviously wrong. I have a table with three columns spnr, ccode and grade. I want to calculate the flow of all of the courses, which is the 1-amountGrade=U/amountAllgrades. The calculation should be made for every course so I'll get a column 'flow' with the percentage of the flow in every course.

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: Post sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Example table(ccode,grade) 1,A : 2,B : 1,C : 2,C : 2,D : 2,U. I want a table that shows table(ccode,flow) 1,100 : 2,75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a whirl. I believe it is what you seek.

```
SELECT
    x.ccode
    , (CAST(ygrade as float)/CAST(xnumber AS FLOAT))*100 AS flow
FROM
(
    SELECT ccode, COUNT(s.ccode) AS xnumber
    FROM Studied s
    GROUP BY ccode
) x
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT ccode, COUNT(grade) as ygrade
        FROM Studied s
        WHERE grade <> 'U'
        GROUP BY ccode
    ) y
        on x.ccode = y.ccode
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some `group by`s and a fix for the integer division.  I would guess this is the query you want:

```
SELECT x.ccode, (1-(cast(ygrade as float)/xnumber))*100 AS flow
FROM (SELECT ccode, COUNT(s.ccode) AS xnumber
      FROM Studied s
      GROUP BY ccode
     ) x JOIN
     (SELECT ccode, COUNT(grade) as ygrade
      FROM Studied s
      WHERE grade <> 'U'
      GROUP BY ccode
     ) y
     on x.ccode = y.ccode;
```

There are easier ways to do this, but this is a fix to your query.

Comment: This gives the wrong answer, this only displays the courses with a grade 'U' and instead of 100% for the other courses it displays 0.0000000. Any way to fix this? Should I build my calculation in another way?